# Client program.cs is never executed when creating Blazor WebAssembly apps in .net 8

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

I am trying to convert a .net 7 Blazor WebAssembly app over to .net 8 but the code inside of the program.cs file (on the client side) never gets run. Consequently, absolutely nothing works. I can't even inject a dependency somewhere because I cant register it in the first place.

This isn't just happening in the app I'm trying to convert either. Creating a new project also has the problem. Here is an example project that contains the issue:

https://github.com/SIBUK/BlazorBug

If you compile and run the app then click on the Counter link it will immediately crash because it tries to inject 'AppService' but it cant do for the reason outlined above.

What is going on here?

Comment: I'm not opening a zip file like that.  Publish it as a straight solution into a repo on Github.

Comment: With .net 8 all render modes will render on the server first. Therefore, it is looking for the service in the servers IServiceCollection... Turn off pre-render

Answer (score 2):

Turn off pre-render.

```html
@page "/counter"
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssemblyNoPreRender

@inject AppService appService;

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    static InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode InteractiveWebAssemblyNoPreRender = new(false);
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This has fixed the problem by forcing the program.cs to run immediately, but I feel like this is workaround rather than a fix. The pre-rendering is one of the main reasons why I want to upgrade to .net 8, so I really dont want to disable it. Also I have been watching many tutorials on .net 8 and Blazor where they demo the various features, including WebAssembly, and none of them have had to disable pre rendering just to make things work.

Comment: Your only other option then is to provide your app service in both the client and the server. If you provide via interface the implementations can be different on both.

Comment: @SimonBailey re being a work around watch the Blazor release video...

Answer (score 0):

The Blazor Web App Client Program.cs does not run in the browser until a component with WebAssembly interactivity is rendered.

Comment: The component does have WebAssembly interactivity. It set to rendermode InteractiveAuto. You can also set it to rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly so its 100% pure webassembly and the same thing still happens.